# How to secure API authentication details in powershell and python scripts

Tags: python, powershell, security, authentication, passwords

So I use both Powershell and Python for accessing and working with APIs as part of my scripts.

But the problem is that I have to type in the user and pass etc, and leave it there in the script. Currently the only thing I do is quite literally leave an base128 encoding of the credentials typed in the script with a line decoding it afterwords.

I dont want to have to have to type my password in a dialogue box since this is meant for quick automation with many APIs. And the scripts+resources are to be portable, meaning I take them to multiple other computers and just run it as is.

How do I make it more secure with my requirements?
Is there something like a lastpass type thing for programming/API with which I can retrieve the appropriate credentials, possibly even from a network folder/database?

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: absolute path with credentials.txt/.json file?

Comment: sure..i guess, but doesnt that still leave it very exposed though? .... Especially if you have to carry it around with the script-files+resources.... I guess I am nt understanding how to do that without it having the same situation as having it written in the script itself? Sorry for my noobishness.

Answer (score 2):

> To store and retrieve encrypted credentials easily, use PowerShell's
>   built-in XML serialization (Clixml):
>
> ```
> $credential = Get-Credential
>
> $credential | Export-CliXml -Path 'C:\My\Path\cred.xml'
> ```
>
> To re-import:
>
> ```
> $credential = Import-CliXml -Path 'C:\My\Path\cred.xml'
> ```
>
> The important thing to remember is that by default this uses the
>   Windows data protection API, and the key used to encrypt the password
>   is specific to both the *user and the machine* that the code is
>   running under.
>
> As a result, the encrypted credential cannot be imported by a
>   different user nor the same user on a different computer.
>
> By encrypting several versions of the same credential with different
>   running users and on different computers, you can have the same secret
>   available to multiple users.
>
> By putting the user and computer name in the file name, you can store
>   all of the encrypted secrets in a way that allows for the same code to
>   use them without hard coding anything:
>
> ## Encrypter
>
> ```
> # run as each user, and on each computer
>
> $credential = Get-Credential
>
> $credential | Export-CliXml -Path "C:\My\Secrets\myCred_${env:USERNAME}_${env:COMPUTERNAME}.xml"
> ```
>
> ## The code that uses the stored credentials:
>
> ```
> $credential = Import-CliXml -Path "C:\My\Secrets\myCred_${env:USERNAME}_${env:COMPUTERNAME}.xml"
> ```
>
> The correct version of the file for the running user will be loaded
>   automatically (or it will fail because the file doesn't exist).

Comment: woah! thanks.... but how would I do this if I actually have to create new machines/VMs a lot? Do i have to redo everything there? since part of the process of setting up some of the new VMs is to run those scripts and access some of the APIs as part of the setup.

Comment: The way the encryption works with those examples uses a key tied to both the user and machine, so you need to store the credentials once on the new machine as the user.

Comment: hmm ok.. ill try to absorb this..and utilize it.... I wonder if I can expand this to python as well

Comment: @AdilZia yeah it may not be the right approach for your specific situation, but it's something to think about, and one that has helped me a lot in the past.